# Evaluate $I=\int \int _{\delta}(x^my-y^nx)dA$,if $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\delta$ is the part of the unit disc in the upper half-plane

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

using polar cordinates i get the following result,by considering a circle $x^2+y^2\le 1$ and $y\ge 0$

$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^1 (r^m\cos^m\theta r\sin \theta-r^n\sin^n\theta r\sin \theta  \cos \theta)rdrd\theta=\dfrac{(-1)^m+1}{m^2+4m+3}$

however i want to find the solution without using polar cordinates(*maybe directly*),is this possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the domain of integration is symmetric with respect to $x$ ($(x,y)\in \delta \iff (-x,y)\in\delta$), we have

$$\iint_\delta y^nx\,dA = 0$$

by parity. Also by parity, we have

$$\iint_\delta x^my\,dA = 0$$

for odd $m$. For even $m = 2k$, we compute

$$\begin{align}
\iint_\delta x^{2k}y\,dA &= \int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x^{2k}y\,dy\,dx\\
&= \int_{-1}^1 x^{2k}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}y\,dy\,dx\\
&= \int_{-1}^1 x^{2k}\frac{1}{2}\left(1-x^2\right)\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 x^{2k} - x^{2k+2}\,dx\\
&= \int_0^1 x^m - x^{m+2}\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{m+1} - \frac{1}{m+3}\\
&= \frac{2}{(m+1)(m+3)}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: the parity argument works very well,so for even $m$ its  $\dfrac{2}{(m+1)(m+3)}$ and for odd its $1$

Comment: For odd $m$ it's $0$, I suppose the $1$ in your comment is just a typo?

Comment: oh yes,i see,thats a nice solution @Daniel Fischer